Windows11: where is my current desktop background image file in slideshow?
My desktop background is set to slideshow. At this moment I am seeing an image on the desktop. How do I find the corresponding image file?
For example, it would  be enough to find the slideshow  folder and look for a similar image there  manually.
What I tried:

Right-click  on the desktop / Personalize / Background / Slideshow  /  Browse button. This opens C:\Users\<my name >\OneDrive\Pictures with a few subfolders, but no image files at all.

NEW EDIT: There is an allegely similar question  about Windows-10, but that one is not specific for slideshow  The accepted answer there  only gives some predefined Windows path for a (static ) copy of the  fixed background image, NOT the path the the configured  slideshow  folder.
My question is NOT a duplicate of that one. I still urgently need an answer.
Please read and understand  my question  before closning it.
Actually almost all questions on this site are about the same: Windows or even computer software. Then the all are duplicates. So the entire site  is to be closed. But please keep my question! This site is for asking for help and giving help, not for arbitrary  censorship!
PLEAS re- open this question!

Even recursing into the subfolders shows no image files, but only a few .ini files.

Any other way to find where my slideshow is located?
EDIT:  Some users suggested that this question is a duplicate of allegely  similarly-looking  existing questions, but in fact   asking different things.
I clarify that in my case  the desktop background   is not  the one preset with Windows or installed with a  professionally-made theme.  I think at some point I  changed the desktop  background to  slideshow folder  with my own  images. I think that the landscape that I am  seeing  in the slideshow at this moment  is my own (I kind of recognize the place.) But I have many thousands photos scattered all over my disks
So my question  is not about some predefined folder and not about  themes installed  with an automatic installer. I ask  which  folder  the custom slideshow is set to. Ideally, I would even like to know which file from the slideshow folder is  shown at this moment. Of course, if I knew  which folder contains the slideshow  images, I could find a similar image there manually. So my question is  about where all my  custom slideshow images are located. I know  that many months (or years) I  configured  this setting myself, but I don't remember it So my question is about how I can  find out  what setting I configured for the custom slideshow background.
By slideshow I mean that my custom background  changes every  minute or every several  minutes, using images from some folder that years ago I myself  specified  somehow.
This is not a duplicate of questions asking  about some predefined  Windows directory. Also, I have indicated that my question is about Windows-11. For Windows-7  the answer is likely different.

When you've in Slideshow mode, the Browse button opens a Select Folder dialog set to only display folders and no other filesystem objects. It also defaults to opening in the folder currently selected, so you can look at the top field to see where you are in the filesystem, and then open a normal Explorer window to see the full contents of that directory. Marked duplicates don't have to ask the same question, they only have to have the right answer. This is why questions marked duplicate are not deleted.

Can you check it at
Windows + R  regedit
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WallPaper

More Precise way:
We have a slideshow here 
Go to regedit and find it by folder name:
Dig into it with Ctrl + F

You can see the path to folder


Sorry, I don't understand what to search for in Regedit. You say by folder name, but my question is how to  know what folder is set for the slideshow.  I don't know the folder name.

Okay if you don't know the folder name yet, you can find it at this regedit folder, inside those hash codes, there is a wallpaper key with the location of the image. Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VirtualDesktops\Desktops
